# Should/could I use access tokens for Google Spreadsheets API instead of username/password?

Tags: ruby, security, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org) library to run a sort of program with Google Spreadsheet as a database of sorts.

It's only intended for my use, but if anyone else wants to try and use it they need to log in with their Google account (username and password). In putting simple `gets` functions I'm aware people may be hesitant to do this, and in the response upon login I've noticed access tokens can be used instead:

```
oo = Roo::Google.new(sheetkey, user: GOOGLE_MAIL, password: G> => 
#<Roo::Google:0x3429798 @filename="**the Google spreadsheet key**",
@user="myemailaddress@gmail.com\n", @password="*SECRET!*\n", @access_token=nil ,
...
```

Could I/should I use an access token in this case? I've not done something with an API in this way before but have made maps with Google Maps which I think used an access token to allow a greater number of calls to the API... Would this simplify matters for me or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Would giving out an access token allow people into my account i.e. have my permissions on Google Drive (clearly not what I want)?

I've set the document in question to public and it says "does not require sign in to view" but I understand that this might not hold for programs accessing the API.

Answer (score 1):

**Access Tokens**: Yes, if you want others to be able to use code to access your spreadsheet, you can give them an access token. This will mean they can only access your spreadsheets (access is defined in the scope).

I assume your plan is to make the **code public**.

issues:

A) You will need both the access token and **refresh token**, as access tokens quickly expire, maybe after 1 hour (not sure).

B) I would create a 2nd Google account, that way they can't access all your spreadsheets.

Example OAuth code: Have a look at DrEdit for some example code that uses access tokens.

Note: Google-apps-script might be another option, simpler to use than google-spreadsheet-api

Comment: [it's on Github](https://github.com/lmmx/watir-paper-scanner/blob/master/bookworm.rb) so yes it's public, sorry should've said. I'm not using the google-spreadsheet-api gem to my knowledge, google_drive actually, just tagged it as that since it's using Google Spreadsheets & an api... Thanks for the pointers! Second Google account is a good idea even though kinda messy, I already have one though through an alternative email address, so I guess it's not a problem

Comment: I suspect roo does use google-spreadsheet-api/gdata, there is no other API AFAIN that works that way.